# Send a value to PayPal and have it returned

Tags: php, paypal

I've been trying for over a week to get a value that I send to paypal returned. I've tried everything I have found on the internet to no avail, and I have very little hair left to pull out...

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr>" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$pno;?>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

and

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?custom=<?$pno;?>>" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

and many many variations on those themes. None of it works. When I try to assign $_POST['custom'], it's empty - every time.

The client's PayPal account is a business account and auto-return is on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With an integration that uses no API you can never depend on any return to happen, so that is your first mistake.

The best solution is to use this API-based integration: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

You'll need two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', which return JSON.

Pair the routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

The purchase_unit object can contain a custom_id https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request